# Zend: How to use SQL query with 'like' keyword?

Tags: sql, zend-framework

I am using zend framework. I am using following query in zend and it is working for me perfectly.

```
$table = $this->getDbTable();
$select = $table->select();
$select->where('name = ?', 'UserName');
$rows = $table->fetchAll($select);
```

Now I want to create another query in zend with 'like' keyword. In simple SQL it is like that.

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE name LIKE 'U%'
```

Now how to convert my zend code for above query?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try:

```
$table = $this->getDbTable();
$select = $table->select();
$select->where('name LIKE ?', 'UserName%');
$rows = $table->fetchAll($select);
```

or if UserName is a variable:

```
$table = $this->getDbTable();
$select = $table->select();
$select->where('name LIKE ?', $userName.'%');
$rows = $table->fetchAll($select);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = new Application_Model_DbTable_User();
// User List
$uname=$_POST['uname'];

$query = $user
    ->select()
    ->where('firstname LIKE ?', $uname.'%')
    ->ORwhere('lastname LIKE ?', $_POST['lname'].'%')
    ->ORwhere('emailid LIKE ?', $_POST['email'].'%');

$userlist = $user->fetchAll($query);
```